# what is c\ doing in this command?

Tags: sed

```sh
sed -i '/#if UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI > 255/c\/*#if UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI > 255' /usr/src/ixgbevf-2.16.4/src/kcompat.h
```

I am trying to understand the above command but couldn't figure out what `c\` is doing here?

Comment: Did you try looking up the sed man page? Type `man sed` on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` command says to test lines for the regular expression `#if UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI > 255` (because it starts with forward slash), if so, use the [change](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) command to replace the whole line with whatever follows. (the `-i` means in place.)

In this case, it will change the matching line to be the beginning of a block comment (inserts `/*`) per my local testing.